# Оптимизация пайпа в angular

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic

Всем привет, у меня есть пайп:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: 'takeCategory'
})
export class TakeCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(category): any {
        return category.filter(x => x.view == true);
    }
}
```

и компонент в котором я его использую:

```
<ion-content
        [scrollEvents]="true"
>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let c of category">
    <ion-label>{{c.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="c.view"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item
            *ngFor="let cat of category | takeCategory"
            [routerLink]="['/category', cat.name]"
    >
      <ion-label>{{cat.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Все отлично работает, но проблема в том что если допустим будет не две а 50 категорий. Как мне переделать этот пайп что бы не приходилось писать так много логики в пайпе?

Сам массив:

```
0: {id: 0, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 0", view: false}
1: {id: 1, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 1", view: false}
2: {id: 2, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 2", view: false}
3: {id: 3, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 3", view: false}
4: {id: 4, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 4", view: false}
5: {id: 5, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 5", view: false}
6: {id: 6, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 6", view: false}
7: {id: 7, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 7", view: false}
8: {id: 8, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 8", view: false}
9: {id: 9, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 9", view: false}
10: {id: 0, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 0", view: false}
11: {id: 1, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 1", view: false}
12: {id: 2, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 2", view: false}
13: {id: 3, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 3", view: false}
14: {id: 4, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 4", view: false}
15: {id: 5, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 5", view: false}
16: {id: 6, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 6", view: false}
17: {id: 7, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 7", view: false}
18: {id: 8, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 8", view: false}
19: {id: 9, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 9", view: false}
```

Comment: мне немного непонятно что ты именно делаешь, зачем такой хардкод `x.name.includes('Наименование услуги категории 2')`? если говорить абстрактно, по нормальному у тебя должно быть поле `categoryId` и список категорий с `id` и `name`, при выборе категории конвеер будет выполнять фильтрацию только по выбранной категории

Comment: где чекбоксы - там должна быть одна модель, а не несколько, выходит так что если у тебя 50 категорий - ты 50 раз продублируешь `[(ngModel)]="category1-50"`?

Comment: В этом то и проблема, я не понимаю как сделать правильно

Comment: во-1х у тебя должна быть одна модель - `category`, а не `category1-50`. во-2х эта модель и будет одним параметром конвеера. в3х у тебя должен быть список категорий, который не нужно хардкодить в шаблоне, а чтоб можно было отрендерить через `ngFor`

Comment: Немного изменил задачу теперь при клике нужно просто выводить категорию которая выбрана, делаю вот так, но не работает

Comment: у тебя не работает потому что ты не понимаешь как работает модель, для старта посмотри туториалы по `ngModel`, после этого легко разберешься как продолжить, в официальное в доке в принципе хорошие примеры

Comment: Уже что только не перепробовал, все равно не могу понять в чем проблема, значение view в объекте изменяется, а компонент почему то не перерисовывается.

Comment: смысл в том, что `[(ngModel)]` это синтаксический сахар поверх `[ngModel]="category" (ngModelChange)="category = $event"`. У тебя есть 50 категорий, но выбранная категория может быть одна (если чекбоксы), соответственно переменная тоже должна быть одна. Создай переменную `selectedCategory` в классе и передай ее в `[(ngModel)]="selectedCategory"`. У тебя будет список из 20 категорий, но при выборе чекбокса будет сеттиться значение свойства `selectedCategory`. Точно также `selectedCategory` будет использоваться как параметр конвеера. Первый параметр конвеера это значение слева от операнда `|`

Comment: `let category of categories | takeCategory` - первый аргумент метода `transform` - это массив `categories`, далее аргументы идут через двоеточие, вторым параметром будет выбранная категория `let category of categories | takeCategory: selectedCategory`

Comment: метод `transform` будет иметь сигнатуру `transform(categories: Category[], selectedCategory: Category | undefined): Category[]`, и возвращать `if (!selectedCategory) return categories;` если юзер вообще еще не выбирал категорию и `return categories.filter(...)`

Comment: Спасибо большое)